# Removing a CSS margin property when using media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a basic section with a simple CSS property `margin-right=20px;`.
Now, when I'm configuring a media query for that same section, I want to remove the margin-right property. How can it be removed?

I don't want to override it with `margin-right=0px;` because this is not what I need.

Comment: What do you need the margin to be then?..Your request does not seem logical.

Comment: @Paulie_D i want to remove the margin-right property and add a margin:0 auto property.

Comment: Can you show the code for what you have tried?